# How to create article in Drupal 8 via JMeter?

Tags: drupal, jmeter, drupal-8, boundary

I am trying to create a JMeter test case for article creation in Drupal 8. I am able to add steps for other navigations. But when clicking the Create Article button after entering some values in the form fields, from JMeter I am getting HTTP response 200. But the article is not getting created.

If I do the same steps in browser I am getting HTTP response 303 and article getting created successfully.

I found this in request headers of POST request while hitting the Create Article button. I am suspecting this might be the reason Drupal server is not accepting the request. Because I am not sure how this dynamic ID "JJPKbuyIinQT5mQZ" is getting generated

Is this being generated by browser? If yes, how to do the same action in JMeter?

Is this being generated by server? If yes, I don't see this token in previous request, like form_token.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dynamic ID should be automatically generated by JMeter given you tick `Use multipart/form-data for POST` box, this is so called [multipart boundary](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)

[image: JMeter Drupal POST Request]

Other things to be considered:

- Don't forget to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), otherwise you will not be able to even perform a login
- Correlate [`form_build_id` and `form_token`](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2014-03-06/form_build_id-form_token-how-they-are-generated). You can do this using [CSS/JQuery Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter)
- Correlate `changed`, you can generate timestamp like `1532969982` using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like: `${__groovy(Math.round(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000),)}`
- Correlate `created[0][value][date]`. You can do this using [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) like `${__time(YYYY-MM-dd,)}`
- Correlate `created[0][value][time]`. You can do this using the same `__time()` function like `${__time(HH:mm:ss,)}`

That's probably it, other values should be good to be used from the recorder.

[image: JMeter Drupal Login]

Comment: my bad, the culprit was author date, i was correlating created[0][value][date] and created[0][value][time]. After I used your functions, it worked for me!